# How much damage does the Sith Inquisitor ability "Static Shield" absorb?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How much damage does the Sith Inquisitor Static Shield absorb? The ability description reads "A high amount of damage".

- Is it a static number or is it influenced by my stats?
- Does it absorb all types of damage?
- What about DOT's?
- Does the shield cancel DOT's outright? Or only the ticks that fire while the shield is active?

Comment: I found this on TORHead, but I can't verify this (no level 50 character): `At level 50, Static Barrier absorbs 1162 + 327% of Force Healing Bonus before talents. `

Comment: Can the shield crit?

Comment: Sounds legit @RavenDreamer ! Gj !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability Static Shield works very much like "Power Word: Shield" from World of Warcraft. For those who haven't, the ability simply blocks damage, *all damage*, until either its absorption limit is reached, or its duration expires.

Now, to answer your questions:

**Is it a static number or is it influenced by my stats?**

Static Shield seems to be affected by a percentage of your force healing bonus, as per my earlier comment.

**Does it absorb all types of damage?**

Yes.

**What about DOT's?**

DoTs deal damage, hence, they are absorbed.

**Does the shield cancel DOT's outright? Or only the ticks that fire while the shield is active?**

If the shield is present when damage would be done to you, that damage is prevented and absorbed. So only ticks that, well, *tick* while you're under the buff will be prevented. Static Shield has no affect on the duration of debuffs.

**Bonus Question: So what *won't* it do?**

Static shield will only block the damage portion of abilities. Many stuns and interrupts (for example, Electrocute) deal damage in addition to their effect. While this damage will be prevented by the shield, the effect (sun, interrupt, etc) will not.

Comment: The detail of your answers are fantastic. Good to know what it won't do.

Comment: Also, I think the 'all damage' needs an *.  I tested if falling damage was also absorbed, and ... it doesn't (I jumped, almost died, and the shield was still up)

Comment: @Rodolfo - Does falling damage deal Kinetic damage? I was referring to Kinetic, Energy, Elemental, and Internal damage in that quote.

Comment: don't know, but if there's ever a power that lifts you up the ground and lets you drop, you could die from it even with a bubble :)

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party here, but falling damage is entirely separate from regular damage types; nothing mitigates it.